# UIImage and UILabel outside UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

Look at this image:

[alt text http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/4488/picture2ep3.png](http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/4488/picture2ep3.png)

I know how to add UITableView with grouped style and how to add label in any table cell.

But how can I add image and labels on top on the view, like screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Interface Builder, you can just drag these (UILabels and UIImageViews) onto your view. If you're using a UITableViewController, you might want to switch to a standard UIViewController, to give you more control over what goes into the view.

After you've dragged them on, hook them up via outlets (if you want to programatically change/access them) or set their contents in IB and be done with it.